# ASP.NET MVC Razor post form containing partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a ASP.NET view containing a partial view. I reuse the partial view in several other views with different models. The important part of the view looks like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
//TextArea inserted by partial view
@Html.TextArea("content", new { id = "mycontent" })
//Submit button here
```

The corresponding model:

```
public class Entry {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

And controller method:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,Content")] Entry entry) {
   if (ModelState.IsValid) {                
            db.Entries.Add(entry);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ...
   }
}
```

How can I submit this form posting the content of the TextArea to the "Content" of the model without using code like `@Html.TextArea(model => model.Content)`? Do I have to use AJAX?

Comment: use...@Html.TextArea("Content", new { id = "mycontent" })...it will automatically bind to model..

Comment: You have `Bind(Include = "ID,Title,Text")` but class `Entry` does not include a property named `Text` - did you mean 'Content'?

Comment: use [Bind(Include = "ID,Title,Content")]

Comment: Why do you not want to use `@Html.TextArea()` or `@Html.TextAreaFor()`?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the "Text" to "Content" in my question
@Exception I tried your solution and it worked. So, if I want to use the partial view with different models, I always have to edit the string of the TextArea to fit the corresponding model property?

Comment: yes...absolutely ...@Andibioticum

Comment: @Andibioticum...if my answer helped you..plzz upvote accept..so that it might help others also...thankzzz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your partial view instead of using

```
@Html.TextArea("content", new { id = "mycontent" })
```

use this :

```
@Html.TextArea("Content", new { id = "mycontent" })
```

and without using `@Html.TextAreaFor()` data will be bind to model property `Content` and you can get its value in  `Controller`.